# Minimum of $\phi(x)=\frac1{8x-1}+4x^2-x$

Tags: calculus, functions, maxima-minima

> Let $\phi:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be given by $\phi(x)=\dfrac{1}{8x-1}+4x^2-x\;\forall x\in(\frac{1}{8},\infty)$. Find the minimum of $\phi$.

I haven't been able to solve this problem by finding the zeros of $\phi'(x)$ and as that's the only method I know to find the minimum of a function, I'd be very glad if someone could help me with this.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: The function $\phi$ has been pretty much designed to make the computation of roots of the equation $\phi'(x) = 0$ easy. Could you write down your computation for $\phi'(x)$, and solving the equation? Perhaps you made a mistake in some intermediate step. (btw once you find the zeros of $\phi'$, you still need to prove it is a minimum... for example using the second derivative test)

Comment: What is your issue in finding the zeroes of $\phi'(x)=-\frac{8}{(8x-1)^2}+(8x-1)$? $\phi'(x)=0$ is equivalent to $(8x-1)^3=8$, so the only stationary point is at $x=\frac{3}{8}$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Thank you very much for the comments, my issue was that $\phi'(x)=\dfrac{-8+8x(8x-1)^2-(8x-1)^2}{(8x-1)^2}$ and I didn't know how to find the zero(s) of that expression, since the numerator is a polynomial function of degree $3$ and I tried to make the numerator equal to zero but because of your comments I can now see the solution.

Comment: @peek-a-boo (I couldn't @ multiple users, sorry)

Comment: hopefully this exercise shows you that it is not always a good idea to combine things into one big fraction (because it may make a simple problem terribly complicated looking). it just takes a lot of time and practice to get a feeling for when to factor things and when to put everything as one big fraction

Comment: I found a completely algebraic way - no calculus - to solve this. See my amswer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\phi(x)=\frac{1}{(8x-1)}+4x^2-x \implies \phi'(x)=\frac{-8}{(1-x)^2}+8x-1 =0 $$ $$\implies
(8x-1)^3=8 \implies 8x=3 \implies x=3/8$$ Next we get
$$\phi''(x)=\frac{192}{(8x-1)^2}+8 \implies \phi''(8/3)>0$$
Hence $\phi(x)$ has a local minimum at $x=3/8$ and $$\phi_{min}=\phi(3/8)=\frac{11}{16}$$

Comment: The formula for $\phi'(x)$ should have $(8x-1)^2$ in the denominator, not $(1-x)^3$. Check the formula for $\phi''(x)$ too.

Comment: @Barry Cipra Oh! you are right. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

$\begin{array}\\
f(x)
&=\dfrac{1}{8x-1}+4x^2-x\\
&=\dfrac{1}{8x-1}+4x^2-x+\dfrac1{16}-\dfrac1{16}\\
&=\dfrac{1-(8x-1)/16}{8x-1}+(2x-\dfrac14)^2\\
&=\dfrac{17/16-x/2}{8x-1}+\dfrac1{16}(8x-1)^2\\
&=\dfrac1{8x-1}-\dfrac1{16}+\dfrac1{16}(8x-1)^2\\
g(y)
&=\dfrac1{y}-\dfrac1{16}+\dfrac1{16}y^2
\qquad y=8x-1\\
g'(y)
&=-\dfrac1{y^2}+\dfrac{y}{8}\\
&= 0
\qquad\text{when } y = 2\\
g(2)
&=\dfrac12-\dfrac1{16}+\dfrac14\\
&=\dfrac{11}{16}
\qquad\text{at } x=\dfrac{y+1}{8} = \dfrac38\\
\end{array}
$

Since $g(y) \to \infty$
for $y \to 0$
and $y \to \infty$,
this is a minimum.

There may be
an algebraic way to show that
$g(y) \ge g(2)$
but I''ll leave it at this.

(Added later)

Aha!
Here's how to do it.

$\begin{array}\\
g(y)-g(2)
&=\dfrac1{y}-\dfrac1{16}+\dfrac1{16}y^2-\dfrac{11}{16}\\
&=\dfrac1{y}-\dfrac34+\dfrac1{16}y^2\\
&=\dfrac{y^3-12y+16}{16y}\\
&=\dfrac{(y-2)^2(y+4)}{16y}\\
&\ge 0
\qquad\text{for } y \ge 0\\
\end{array}
$